# WordPress wp_mail is duplicating emails by error, how to prevent this error?

Tags: php, wordpress, email, phpmailer, mailer

I made a custom code for sending out emails but when I trigger this code somehow it duplicates more than one emails, sometimes ranging from 2 to 8 emails at a time. I would appreciate any help given for this random glitch.

```
if(!empty(array_search('premium', $email_output)) && !empty($r_email) && strpos($r_email, '@') !== false && empty($_COOKIE['sentList']) && $_COOKIE['sentList'] == false){

$to = $r_email; 

$subject = 'subject'; 

ob_start();  
include trailingslashit( get_template_directory() ) . 'mailtemplate.php'; 
$body = ob_get_clean(); 

$headers = array('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8'); 

if( empty($_COOKIE['sentList']) && $_COOKIE['sentList'] == false ){ 
setcookie("sentList", true, time() + (60 * 5)); 

wp_mail( $to, $subject, $body, $headers ); 

}

}
```

Comment: It would not surprise me if you have browser plugins causing repeat posts. Add some logging, or append random numbers to your subject line to check if you’re getting multiple posts.

Comment: Thank for trying to help! I checked on private mode with no plugins and the issue remains also tried another browser on another PC. I am starting to think it might be a server glitch. I have some hope to get some help via StackOverflow; I been searching forums for hours and still no luck

Comment: Do this: `$subject = 'subject' . rand(0,1000000);`; if the emails you receive have the same number in the subject, it means your code is being run once but resulting in multiple messages. If you get different numbers in each subject, it means your code is being run more than once.

Comment: Thank you! I have tried that and the numbers are random, turns out it's looping a few times even with the cookies set.

Comment: So you need to look at the code that calls the code you posted to find the repeat - in other words the problem is not in the code you posted, but in whatever triggers it.

Comment: its all fixed now :) thank you again!